# How to hide post from Home page..?

Tags: plugins

I want to hide post from Home page. I use (wp Hide post) plugin, but the plugin not working with wp 4.4. Please give some Idea to solve these problem.

Comment: What do you mean by post? Do you output your latest blog posts in homepage or is it a static page?

Comment: I mean after published a post that hide from home page.

Comment: *Please give some Idea to solve these problem* Contact the plugin author for support ;-)

Comment: You're not providing enough information to solve this issue. You need to address the author of plugin because we don't even know what queries etc it's using.

Comment: Hello sorry for my bad English i m not a native speaker. I mean I want to make hide the post from home page after published a post.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to navigate to your site's URL, followed by `/wp-admin/`. 
Login using your username and password. In the left sidebar, click *Posts* tab. There you will find a list of your posts that you have published.

Hover over the title of the post you want to hide. You will see a *Quick Edit* link. Click this link.

[image: WordPress Quick Edit]

In the right side of the Quick Edit menu, just below the *Tags* box, you will see a dropdown. If your post is already published, this dropdown says *Published*. Click the dropdown arrow, and select *Draft*. Now click the blue *Update* button. Go back to your homepage (refresh cache if necessary). The post should be hidden.

Comment: As far as I am aware this only changes the status of the post. I gather the OP wants to either offset the first/newest or exclude an individual post. This can be done but depending upon if they want to code it or use a plugin. The OP needs to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to filter the posts on your homepage. Use this function, which is already included on the sample code on codex :

```
function exclude_single_posts_home($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('post__not_in', array(7,11));
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_single_posts_home');
```

Comment: Oops sorry, Format is perfect now. I just pasted it all the way. Cheers!